# Python Requests Returning 401 code on 'get' method

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, http-status-code-401

I'm working on a webscrape function that's going to be pulling HTML data from internal (non public) servers. I have a connection through a VPN and proxy server so when I ping any public site I get code 200 no problem, but our internals are returning 401.

Heres my code:

```
http_str = f'http://{username}:{password}@proxy.yourorg.com:80'

proxyDict = {
    'http' : http_str, 
    'https' : https_str, 
    'ftp' : https_str
    }

html_text = requests.get(url, verify=True, proxies=proxyDict, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd))
```

I've tried flushing my DNS server, using different certificate chains (that had a whole new list of problems). I'm using urllib3 on version 1.23 because that seemed to help with SSL errors. I've considered using a requests session but I'm not sure what that would change.

Also, the url's we're trying to access DO NOT require a log in. I'm not sure why its throwing 401 errors but the auth is for the proxy server, I think. Any help or idea are appreciated, along with questions as at this point I'm not even sure what to ask to move this along.

Edit: the proxyDict has a string with the user and pwd passed it for each type, https http fts, etc.

Comment: The *auth* param is if the target URL requires authentication. Does it work with auth parameter removed from requests.get()?

Comment: It does not, I've also ignored verification and get the same 401.

Comment: f'xx' is f-string if embedding e.g. "{user}" fields. Try r'xx' for raw string.

Comment: Ok that was an interesting result, the r string didn't work but the f string was working. However, when I switch to r string the proxy tunnel failed for public sites too. So it seems like the proxy works for public domains with f strings. weird. But thats a new error so it sounds like the proxy is working, maybe just not for these internal domains.

Comment: If you don't have any {xx} variables referenced in your *http_str* value then f-string and w/o f prefix in value should be the same. If change code to `http_str = 'http://username:password@proxy.yourorg.com:80'` w/o the f prefix in string does it get the same result?

Comment: my bad, I do have the {user} {pwd} braced. That was the issue with the f string. I will edit again. Sorry, I cant paste my code directly since it's on a dif computer that does not have access to stackoverflow.

Comment: If you're accessing internal URLs then you should not need a proxy. What do you get if drop the proxies and auth params and try requests.get(url, verify=False).

Comment: Disregard all the edits. Still no change. 401 using verify true false, proxys or no proxies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239328/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-rufom1).

Answer (score 0):

To use HTTP Basic Auth with your proxy, use the `http://user:password@host/` syntax in any of the proxy configuration entries. See [apidocs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies).

```python
import requests
proxyDict = {
    "http": "http://username:password@proxy.yourorg.com:80",
    "https": "http://username:password@proxy.yourorg.com:80"
}
url = 'http://myorg.com/example'
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict)
```

If, however, you are accessing internal URLs via VPN (i.e., internal to your organization on your intranet) then you should NOT need the proxy to access them.

Try:

```
import requests
url = 'http://myorg.com/example'
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

Comment: hey sorry I'll edit to clarify but I do have the usename and pwd in the proxy address strings. But it sounds like if I'm adding the proxies I don't need the basicAuth? It's also sounding like my issue may be with the proxy server or proxy credentials...

Comment: Yes, if target URL does not require any authentication then it's an issue with the proxy server or proxy credentials.